# Program to produce svy Ratio in stata

Tags: stata

I wrote the following code to tabulate the mean results for multiple indicators at the same table:

```
program RESULTS_MEANS
syntax varlist

tempname v se

local k : list sizeof varlist
display as txt %12s "Variable"      ///
    as txt %10s "Mean"      ///
    as txt %12s "SE"        ///
    as txt %12s "N"

forval i = 1/`k' {
    local var : word `i' of `varlist'
    quietly svy: mean `var'
    quietly estat size
    quietly estat effects
    matrix `v' = e(V)
    scalar `se' = sqrt(el(`v',1,1)) 

    display   as txt %12s "`var'"           ///
        " "   as res %9.0g _b[`var']        ///
        "   " as res %9.0g `se'             ///
        "   " as res %9.0g e(N)                         
}
end


RESULTS_MEANS var1 var2
```

The results should look like

```
Variable    Mean    SE      N

var1       0.538    0.015   9396

var2       0.191    0.009   9396
```

The problem appears when I modify the program to accommodate the "ratio" case to calculate `var1/var2`.

Here is the modified code:

```
program RESULTS_RATIOS
syntax varlist

tempname v se

local k : list sizeof varlist
display as txt %12s "Variable"      ///
    as txt %10s "Mean"      ///
    as txt %12s "SE"        ///
    as txt %12s "N"

forval i = 1/`k' {
local var : word `i' of `varlist'
    quietly svy: ratio `var'
    quietly estat size
    quietly estat effects
    matrix `v' = e(V)
    scalar `se' = sqrt(el(`v',1,1)) 

    display   as txt %12s "`var'"           ///
        " "   as res %9.0g _b[`var']        ///
        "   " as res %9.0g `se'             ///
        "   " as res %9.0g e(N)                         
}
end


RESULTS_RATIOS (var1/var2)
```

Stata gives me this error

```
/ invalid name
```

Any suggestions on how to modify the code???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `syntax` command tells Stata that the arguments to your program are a list of variable names, and `var1/var2` is not a variable name. You need a different syntax statement. Below is a demonstration of your problem and its solution.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. generate var1 = 1

. generate var2 = 2

. program RR
  1. syntax varlist
  2. display "parsed list: `varlist'"
  3. end

. RR var1 var2
parsed list: var1 var2

. RR var3
variable var3 not found
r(111);

. RR var1/var2
/ invalid name
r(198);

. program SS
  1. syntax anything
  2. display "parsed list: `anything'"
  3. end

. SS var1 var2
parsed list: var1 var2

. SS var3
parsed list: var3

. SS var1/var2
parsed list: var1/var2

.
```

Comment: @ William Lisowski replacing varlist with anything works. However, it doe not work when you have multiple set of ratios, such as RESULTS_RATIOS var1/var2  var3/var4 .... any suggestions?

Comment: That's because you can't feed (e.g.) `var1/var2` to `mean`, which in turn requires a _varlist_. You'll need to create a variable on the fly.

Comment: My first suggestion would be that you report not just that it doesn't work, but also what the error message is. My guess is that the `ratio` comand in your modified code failed because the syntax for the `ratio` command with more than one ratio specified requires parentheses around each ratio. I think you need to call your program with a command somewhat like `SS (var1/var2) (var3/var4)` but since I do not use the `ratio` command I am not certain. Look at `help ratio` to learn the proper syntax.

Comment: the error is `invalid ratio specification: too many '/'` ... when I use `SS (var1/var2) (var3/var4)` instead, it considers the whole line as the one ratio. it produces the results of the first ratio though `var1/var2`

Comment: In your modified code, remove the `local k` command, and replace the `forval i` and `local var` commands with `foreach var of local anything`. Look at `help foreach` for syntax advice. And if that cannot be made to work, edit your question and add (without deleting anything that is currently part of the question) a new block of code that shows how your code now looks.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. here's the final code

```
program RESULTS_RATIOS
syntax anything

tempname v se

local k : list sizeof anything
display as txt %12s "Variable"      ///
    as txt %10s "Mean"      ///
    as txt %12s "SE"        ///
    as txt %12s "N"

forval i = 1/`k' {
local var : word `i' of `anything'
    quietly svy: ratio `var'
    quietly estat size
    quietly estat effects
    matrix `v' = e(V)
    scalar `se' = sqrt(el(`v',1,1)) 

    display   as txt %12s "`var'"           ///
        " "   as res %9.0g _b[`var']        ///
        "   " as res %9.0g `se'             ///
        "   " as res %9.0g e(N)                         
}
end

RESULTS_RATIOS var1/var2 var3/var4
```